# Can't connect to local IIS7 site I've set up

Tags: .net, iis-7, web

- I've set up a .NET web application within IIS7 on my local computer
- I've created it as an actual separate website in IIS and named the website 'abcd'
- I've set the correct application pool and physical path for the site
- I've added a binding for the site with Type=http, Host Name=xyz, Port=80, IP Address=*
- I've edited my local 'hosts' file and have added the line:

  - `#    127.0.0.1       xyz`
- The application doesn't need to be available to the outside world just now.  I've given the NETWORK SERVICE account the following permissions on the parent folder for the application:

  - Read & execute, List folder contents, Read, Write
- The NETWORK SERVICE account also has the following permissions for files within the folder:

  - Read & execute, Read, Write

When I try to browse the site in IE by using the address `http://xyz` I get a message that starts:

This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address `http://alsmbcdlocal` is correct.
 ...

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the first `#` sign in your hosts file commenting out the whole line?  It's not mapping xyz to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Doh!  The benefit of a fresh pair of eyes!  Thanks.  Make this the answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the first # sign in your hosts file commenting out the whole line? It's not mapping xyz to 127.0.0.1.

Fresh eyes are a WHOLE lot of help sometimes.  I was almost hesitant to post that as a comment.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove the `#` sign?

It should show

127.0.0.1       xyz instead of #    127.0.0.1       xyz

the # is to comment. :)